# Meaning of Firefox 4's error console showing "CoCreateInstance() FAILED"

Tags: firefox4

While running Selenium IDE tests on Firefox 4, I seem to get in the FF4-built-in Error Console a number of these messages (meaning Messages, as opposed to Errors, etc.), but I can't quite tell at what point they're occurring or what might be the cause.  I'm not sure whether it's even a Selenium issue or something on one of my pages causing it.

```
CoCreateInstance() FAILED.
```

Are they cause for alarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoCreateInstance` is a function in the Windows implementation of the Component Object Model (COM). Firefox uses a binary-compatible clone of COM as part of its native-code architecture, which is likely the way that Selenium allows you to control parts of Firefox that aren't exposed via JavaScript.

So it's plausible that the CoCreateInstance messages are from Selenium, but it could be Firefox itself. You could create a new Firefox profile without Selenium installed and try navigating to the test page that triggers the log messages, and manually performing the test actions that trigger the messages. If you still get the messages, then Selenium is probably not the source of the errors. You could also try running the tests with Selenium on on Firefox 3.6. If the messages go away, then it's probably a (likely minor) incompatibility between Selenium and the latest build of Firefox.

The messages are probably not cause for alarm, so long as it's not interfering with your tests.

Comment: Turns out the following page causes it even with all my add-ons disabled, includin Selenium: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><body onload="prompt('hi')"></body></html>>`.  However, in Safe Mode, this does not happen.  Also there must be other causes, because three other instances of that message are logged when Firefox first starts, but not in Safe Mode.

Comment: Curious! Sounds like it might be a bug in the Firefox 4 beta. There are a few CoCreateInstance related bugs in Bugzilla, but I don't see any that are triggered by malformed HTML5. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=CoCreateInstance Perhaps you could file a bug if you can reproduce the messages with the latest Firefox nightly build?